# Hiding status bar for one View Controller while showing rest in white

Tags: ios, hide, viewcontroller, statusbar

I have an app where I would like the status bar of just the first View Controller to be hidden (sort of like an intro screen). All of the View Controllers that follow should, however, show the status bar. **I realize this is a common question but mine is different for this reason:**

I have already gone into Info.plist and set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` because I want the status bars in the rest of the application to be white. I did this with the following line of code in the App Delegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

For this reason, I can't use the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method in my View Controller to individually hide the status bar.

Is there any way I can just hide the status bar in this one View Controller without setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in Info.plist? (because doing so would mean that I would have to *manually* go to every following View Controller and set the status bar color to white instead of doing everything in AppDelegate as shown above)

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear function of your first view controller, hide the status bar:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
```

In it's viewWillDisappear function, show it:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, animation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
```